# Operaciones con excel en python

Tags: python, excel

A partir de un excel importado en python estoy tomando columnas y realizando una media del valor de sus celdas. El primer bucle es simplemente para que me imprima toda la info del excel (es uno cortito para pruebas), luego establezco las variables para cada celda y hago la operación en una función que luego llamo a imprimir para que me de el resultado de la primera columna simplemente.

**La duda es que no se como hacer para no tener que establecer una variable para cada celda (no se si en verdad es posible simplificarlo).**

Aquí el código:

```
import xlrd

ubicaciOn=str(input("Introduce la ubicaciOn del documento: "))

abrirDoc = xlrd.open_workbook(ubicaciOn)

hoja = abrirDoc.sheet_by_name("Hoja1")

for i in range(hoja.ncols):
    print(hoja.cell_value(i,0), "        ", hoja.cell_value(i,1), "        ", hoja.cell_value(i,2), "        ", hoja.cell_value(i,3))

contenido_celda0 = hoja.cell_value(0,0)
contenido_celda1 = hoja.cell_value(1,0)
contenido_celda2 = hoja.cell_value(2,0)
contenido_celda3 = hoja.cell_value(3,0)

def media_celdas():

    return (contenido_celda0 + contenido_celda1 + contenido_celda2 + contenido_celda3)/4

print(media_celdas())
```

y aquí los datos del excel:
[image: Valores del excel]

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar col_values para reducir las variables:

```
def media_celdas(column)
    suma = 0 
    for i in hoja.col_values(column)
        suma += i
    return suma / hoja.nrows
```